# Allow sftp connection to one folder

Tags: chroot

I need to allow user "vine" to to transfer files with sftp to my server in certain folder /data/xxx/. Ssh should not be allowed.

Addition to that another user "beer" needs to be able to read and delete transferred files from the xxx folder.

I am using RHEL 6.6 and openSSH 5.3 p1.

I have tried several options, but no breakthrough. Any help on this?

This is the latest attemp, but giving following error:

Write failed: Broken pipe
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer

Something to do with the access rights.

```
    #!/bin/sh

######################################################
# Create a new SFTP user and configure their chroot
######################################################

# "Create sftpusers Group"
groupadd sftpusers

# "Create vine user"
useradd -g sftpusers -s /sbin/nologin vine

# # Create password for vine user."
echo -e vine#1234 | passwd vine --stdin

# "Modify beer to sftpusers group."
usermod -a -G sftpusers beer

# "Setup sftp-server Subsystem in sshd_config."

sed -e '/Subsystem/ s/^#*/#/' -i /etc/ssh/sshd_config

echo "Subsystem       sftp    internal-sftp" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config

echo "Match Group sftpusers" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo "        ChrootDirectory /Data/sftp/%u" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config
echo "        ForceCommand internal-sftp" >> /etc/ssh/sshd_config


# "Create sftp Home Directory"
mkdir -p /data/sftp/vine/
chown -R root:root /data/sftp/vine
#mkdir /data/sftp/vine
#chown root:root /data/sftp/vine
mkdir /data/sftp/vine/incoming

# "Setup Appropriate Permission"
chown vine:sftpusers /data/sftp/vine/incoming

# "Restart sshd and Test Chroot SFTP"
service sshd restart

chmod -R 755 /data
```

Answer (score 0):

The usual way to handle this involves setting up chroot.  This worked well for me:  https://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/sftp-logging-chroot/  (Ubuntu)